# SQL Server IO Statistics Read Types

Tags: sql-server

Using

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
```

results in message such as

> Table 'foo'. Scan count 1, logical reads 896, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 72, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

What do the various data actually mean and why are they important?

1. scan count
2. logical reads
3. physical reads
4. read-ahead reads
5. lob logical reads
6. lob physical reads
7. lob read-ahead reads

Answer (score 0):

Technet has a [table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx) with the answers.

[image]